# Cancelling The Transaction

Tags: c#

If the user or the customer cancel the transaction , how can i bring the quantity to stocks to its same state before in datagridview.

like in the picture below when i add to cart it minus the stocks by quantity and inserted in the datagrid and same goes to remove to cart but added the stocks by quantity , so if the customer or the user cancel the transaction how to bring it back stocks to its before state ?

thank you in advance !

[image]

Comment: Store the data that you need to "back up", you'll then have a copy of it should the user cancel and you need to invert the last operation.

Comment: In the same way you minus the stock

Comment: I just read POS - is this application for a point of sale where the customer has the articles to buy already "in his hand" or is it a remote app where you order the articles?

Answer (score 0):

Identify the `datarow` and call the `RejectChanges()` on that row.

MSDN link for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rejectchanges(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: what if the user enters more than 1 data ?

Comment: then find both/all the selected rows, and call RejectChanges() on both/all.